# No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, methods, error-handling

This is the error.

```
Atrosity [ Eric-Raios-MacBook ][ ~/dev/rubyscripts ]$ ruby script.rb 
script.rb:7:in `read': No such file or directory - sent (Errno::ENOENT)
from script.rb:7:in `lSent'
from script.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

My Method that is causing the error is:

```
def lSent
  $sent = Set.new(File.read("sent").split(";"))
end

lSent
```

If I delete this, my script runs but does not output what I want to do.

Comment: You can check if a file exists using `File.exist?(filename)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sent` should be a path to a file in your server, such as

```
$sent = Set.new(File.read("/root/path/file.txt").split(";"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You're attempting to read a file called "sent", but it doesn't exist in the application's path. Try including the full path to the file.